# How do you prevent jQueryUI's draggable interaction from going past a certain offset on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am using jQuery UI (latest version). We have a separator bar on our page that is similar to that of jsfiddle. It can only be dragged along the x-axis, but the problem we are having is getting it to stop at a certain point.

When the bar gets to within 250px of either edge of the window, we want it to stop. I did find this 'solution' which doesn't really work for us however:

**on drag event in jQueryUI, stopDragging() is called**:

```
function stopDragging() {

    console.log( $('#dragbar').offset().left );

    if ( $('#dragbar').offset().left < 250 )
    {
        $('#dragbar').trigger('mouseup');
    }
}
```

However, this throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

This method also releases the mouse grasp on the drag bar. I would like for the behavior to be such that if a user drags to this point, they cannot drag it any further - and if they do not release the click and drag the other way, it will still work.

**UPDATE**

See this fiddle for an example. When you drag, the green and blue will resize accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/U95hW/1/

**UPDATE 2**

I created this fiddle to be a bit closer to the final result. When I added the margins as suggested by @ntgCleaner, it changes the position of the bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/U95hW/8/

Comment: Look in the console for a stacktrace, see which line (in your code) is the culprit.

Comment: Have you tried making a container that has 250px margin on either side, then make that container the draggable 'container'? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement  You can also give the element that you're dragging a 250px margin and it should 'count' as the entire draggable

Comment: Frits - the error is in jqueryui.js

Comment: ntgCleaner: That is not really an option, because i have two divs with percentage widths on either side of the drag bar. That bar adjusts their widths accordingly.

Comment: is 250px a constant? or does that adjust with the size of the screen as well?  Not sure if you had seen the second half of my above comment (edited afterwards) with adding 250px margin to the draggable?

Comment: it would still allow it to drag beyond the confines of the screen though, the margin would just disappear

Comment: Are you able to post your html and CSS in a fiddle so we can see how it's laid out?

Comment: i have posted the code in the second link!

Comment: I'm taking a look at your fiddles, but can you take a look at this link and let me know if this is what you are trying to do?  http://412webdesigns.com/playground/tempGo/reg_12345.html  The orange bar moves with the slider

Comment: That is very close to what i am trying to accomplish, just have to be mindful of the div to the right also

Comment: Ok, Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: Check out this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U95hW/73/.  Besides the fact that it doesn't load in the center on load (which can be fixed with more javascript) this looks like it works like you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to ntgCleaner**, i was able to solve this issue. I did not use his solution, but he did get me going in the correct direction.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/U95hW/87/

What i did, was to use `$.resizable()`. This allowed me the flexibility of being able to control how small or wide it could go, while choosing what edge I wanted to be draggable.

I was able to use my `dragbar` element as a handle for the widget, and all was well!

Thanks to everyone involved!